# Are meteors visible on Mars?

Tags: mars, meteor, naked-eye

If a person were standing on the surface of Mars, under ideal viewing conditions for seeing a meteor: no clouds, the sun has long set, would a meteor be visible to the naked eye considering how thin the Martian atmosphere is?

Comment: You can see a meteorite (a meteor that survives all the way to the surface) that landed on Mars here: https://space.stackexchange.com/a/24660/12102 Also check out  [What will shooting stars look like on Mars?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27073/12102) and also [How small must an asteroid be to burn entirely in the martian atmosphere?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34296/12102)

Answer (score 8):

> [First Shooting Star Seen from Mars](https://www.space.com/1155-shooting-star-mars.html)
>   
>   space.com  2005
>   [image]
>   The background image shows the meteor near the top-left and the horizon at the bottom. A red arrow shows the direction of travel. The inset is a larger version of the meteor itself. The graph is a "light curve" that aided in tying the meteor to comet Wiseman–Skiff.
>   (Image: © Nature/NASA/Spirit/F. Selsis et al.)

This was made by Spirit's panoramic camera, so it probably would be visible to the naked (helmeted) eye.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There actually is an example. From the below text:

> Dust from the comet impacted Mars and was vaporized high in the atmosphere, producing what was likely an impressive meteor shower.

https://www.nasa.gov/press/2014/november/mars-spacecraft-reveal-comet-flyby-effects-on-martian-atmosphere/#.VF9fLPTF9vR

Comment: Well... that article says the dust led to a long-lasting ion cloud which is what produced photons (mostly UV).  If the OP wanted to know whether a meteor would heat up and produce a streak as happens on Earth, that's not quite clear.

Comment: The articles states that there must have been an impressive meteor shower, which would be the visible part. I wasn't aware that there actually is a photo of a meteor on Mars, so there is that. @Keith McClary's answer deserves to be accepted, imo.